# Can i use a dropdown selection on a Material Design card

Tags: user-behavior, material-design, ux-designer

So i made a Material Design Card, but as usual after feedback a problem hit my mind.

Can i use a dropdown selection on a Material Design card, let me explain a little more, in this app witch i cant reveal its main function but lets give it a try, theres a Admin user that can create, delete and Edit... so this User needs to fill a couple of data to make this event witch include: Location, Name, Location, Short Description and a Benefit (This is where we want to make the dropdown selection) so there would be options like: 2x1, Ladies Night, Free, etc.

All this is made on a Material Design Card, but im not sure if those can contain Dropdowns.

Below you guys can find a photo of the card (Its on spanish but i guess it will work)

The section with the red rectangle line its the topic on discussion, in this photo ITS NOT a dropdown, just a text field where the user can write the benefit (We prefer not to do that)

Here's the link to the Material Design Card:

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html

[image]

Comment: What was the feedback? I think it might be an important piece of information for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefit of a 'card' style UI is for important information to be surfaced where it is required to allow the user to perform a task or achieve some goal. While there's really nothing to say that you can't put a dropdown (just think about how many Windows Metro or Apple standards/guidelines don't get followed), perhaps you can consider other ways to surface that information, especially when there can be more than one type of benefit (and there aren't say like ten of then, so maybe toggle buttons?).

But I think the more important question to consider is whether you can maintain a consistent style and pattern in how you use the 'card' UI in the rest of your application, so that you can achieve a consistent and fluent user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: yes. You can use a Simple Menu. https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-behavior

There are no specific guidelines around this exact case but you can get a good idea of how the Simple Menu can and cannot be used in the above link.